# Fix foreign key issue: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_MDM.membership_registration
(
    registration_num INT Primary key,
    registration_location VARCHAR(25),
    customerID INT /* FOREIGN KEY Customer details */,
    first_name VARCHAR(25),
    last_name VARCHAR(25),
    dob DATE,
    marital_status VARCHAR(25),
    gender VARCHAR(25),
    occupation VARCHAR(25),
    income_level VARCHAR(25),
    date_enrolled VARCHAR(25),
    phone_number VARCHAR(25),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    city VARCHAR(25),
    state VARCHAR(25),
    zipcode INT
);
```

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_MDM.loyalty_data
(
    customerID INT,
    loyalty_level INT,
    customer_age INT,
    reward_points INT,
    average_amount_spend INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration') */,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration') */,
    dob DATE /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration') */,
    marital_status VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration') */,
    gender VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY (‘Membership_registration') */,
    occupation VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY (Membership_registration'') */,
    income_level VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY (‘Membership_registration') */, 
    city VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration') */,
    state VARCHAR(25) /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration’) */,
    zipcode INT /* FOREIGN KEY ('Membership_registration') */,
    PRIMARY KEY(customerID,loyalty_level)
);
```

Finally:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer_MDM.loyalty_data 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (first_name) 
        REFERENCES Customer_MDM.membership_registration(first_name);
```

Trying to execute the `ALTER TABLE` statement I get these errors:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 42
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Customer_MDM.membership_registration' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__loyalty_d__first__634EBE90'
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Your entire approach is just wrong. Remove the duplicated columns and form a relationship with the primary key as already suggested. And I HOPE that this information is securely stored (perhaps even encrypted). And your datatypes are a mess - get help!

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(customerID,loyalty_level)` So a given customer has multiple rows in this table? And where is the FK to customer? I think you have much bigger schema issues to address before you attempt to create this table.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all these complexities, simply create foreign key for membership table, once. Then all the other columns can be easily referenced.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_MDM.loyalty_data (
    customerID INT,
    loyalty_level INT,
    customer_age INT,
    reward_points INT,
    average_amount_spend INT,
    registration_num INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(customerID,loyalty_level),
    FOREIGN KEY (registration_num) REFERENCES Customer_MDM.membership_registration(registration_num)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique index on first name in the membership_registration table first.  Hopefully you're not actually trying to foreign key something by the first name and this is just testing foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the table `membership_registration` you need to make sure the column  `first_name` is a key. It can be a primary key or a unique constraint.

Since the table already has a primary key, you can define this column with a unique constraint. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_MDM.membership_registration(
  registration_num INT Primary key,
  registration_location VARCHAR(25),
  customerID INT /* FOREIGN KEY Customer details */,
  first_name VARCHAR(25),
  last_name VARCHAR(25),
  dob DATE,
  marital_status VARCHAR(25),
  gender VARCHAR(25),
  occupation VARCHAR(25),
  income_level VARCHAR(25),
  date_enrolled VARCHAR(25),
  phone_number VARCHAR(25),
  email VARCHAR(30),
  city VARCHAR(25),
  state VARCHAR(25),
  zipcode INT,
  constraint uq1 UNIQUE (first_name) -- added constraint here
);
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8359d4eca28f2235dbdcbc1a9f0661a).

In any case, first names are not good choices for a key since most likely your data model will need to accomodate multiple people with the same name.

Comment: so for example if i want to use more alter statements for lastname, dob, gender. i will have to create unique constraint for all of them?

Comment: if i give unique constraint for firstname than i won't be able to add same firstname and in a dataset you can have same name sometimes so how will it makes sense?

Comment: Foreign keys can only reference "primary keys" or "unique constraints". So, yes.

Comment: @srujalpatel As their name implies "foreign keys" are reference to keys. The keys won't allow duplicates. I would suggest you revisit the theory about keys and foreign keys and normalization (3NF).

Comment: @srujalpatel how would you expect a FK based on Firstname to work? You wouldn't know which of the duplicates it refers to... so there is a flaw in this design.